# Could not initialize class mono.android.D3DImageFactory in (xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, mono

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class mono.android.D3DImageFactory
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at mono.android.DesignerSession.initializePlatformSpecific(DesignerSession.java:86)
at mono.android.DesignerSession.<init>(DesignerSession.java:75)
at mono.android.Project.createSession(Project.java:382)
at mono.android.Project.processMessage(Project.java:414)
at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried to update the JDK to the last version and  change the directory of the JDK in tools => xamarin => option but it doesn't work .

Comment: You could read this : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/101891/wrong-could-not-initialize-class-mono-android-d3dimagenfactory

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT thanks for your answer , i have already seen this question . i tried all the solutions mentioned by none of them works . i am using the last version of xamarin . VS2017 and VS2015 Xamarin.Andorid 7.4.0.21 . some people say that i need to use a 64 bit jdk . my system is 32 bit so i can't use a 64 bit jdk . I downgrade my xamarin to 4.2.1 and it's working . until i get an answer from xamarin support ,